# ionic2 in a modal page navigate to another page ？

Tags: angular, ionic2

When I push another page in my modal using `this.navCtrl.push(TwoPage)`, the pushed page displays like this:

[image]

The modal was created as follows:

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(OnePage);
modal.present();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the **Navigating from an Overlay Component** section in [the Ionic doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component)

Try in your modal:

```
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

The constructor: Inject App

```
 constructor(
      public viewCtrl: ViewController
      public app: App
    ) {}
```

Inorder to navigate,

```
this.app.getRootNav().push(TwoPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to update, *getRootNav()* is deprecated and now you have to use:

```
this.app.getActiveNav().push(TwoPage);
```

but this will be also deprecated and the recommendation is to use *getActiveNavs()* which returns an array of active NavControllers, so at your own risk you could use it this way:

```
this.app.getActiveNavs()[0].push(TwoPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

### IONIC 3:

You should avoid to push directly from modal navigator, instead try to do:

```
constructor(
      private appCtrl: App,
      ...
```

Then , in you method do:

```
this.appCtrl.getRootNavs()[0].push(YourNextPage);
```